# C++ - /tmp/cckpbRW.o:main.cc:(.text+0x9d):undefined reference

Tags: c++, undefined-reference

Following the example here: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/19-header-files/

Relating to `add.h` and `main.cpp`

When I try to compile main.cc (I just used another extension), I get the following:

```
/tmp/cckpbRW.o:main.cc:(.text+0x9d):undefined reference to 'add(int, int)' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your didn't link your `main` object to your `add` one, so when the linker tries to build the executables it cannot find the definition of symbol `add(int, int)` it uses.

You should compile `main` object, `add` object and link them together, like this:

```
g++ -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -c -o add.o add.cpp
g++ -o executable main.o add.o
```

or

```
g++ -o executable main.cpp add.cpp
```

this will compile add.cpp and main.cpp together

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It worked now. So, is the "key" to compile them together? Why did you use "link them together" while what we are doing is compiling the two objects? Thanks.

Comment: @pero. If I use the first form of your solution I get the same error. I typed for example ---> g++ main.cc -o main.o (I'm using Cygwin). Why does the error appear? Thanks.

Comment: @SWEngineer: you need to use -c, to tell the compiler not to link, but just to compile (and/or assemble).
Compilation of a program is made of several phases. The last one is linking, it's when you actually build your executable, putting in it all the things in your source files.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are not linking the second `.cpp` file into final executable. Either compile and link them at the same time:

```
$ c++ -Wall -Werror -pedantic -g -otest1 add.cpp main.cpp
```

or compile them separately and then link:

```
$ c++ -Wall -Werror -pedantic -g -c main.cpp
$ c++ -Wall -Werror -pedantic -g -c add.cpp
$ c++ -Wall -Werror -pedantic -g -otest1 add.o main.o
```